# Return the item description with path JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to appear within the tag `<p>` the description of the selected item in the menu, but I'm back with an error all the html. Anyone know what property should I use?

The path json is:
data.query.results.channel.item.description

javascript:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function (data) {

    // Load Titles patch Json
    console.log(data.query.results.channel.item);
    var titles = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function(item) {
    return item.title;

    });
    var urls = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function(item) {
        return item.origLink;

    });

    var descri = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function(item) {
        return item.description;

    });

     $(".description-podcast p").text(descri);

    console.log(titles);
    $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>'));
    $(".container-list-podcast ul li").each(function(key, value){
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<a href="' + urls[key] + '">' + text + '</a>');
    });
    // Load Navigation Only Key
        a=$('.nav_holder li a').keynav(function() {
            return window.keyNavigationDisabled;
        });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf5QU/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         $(".description-podcast p").html(descri);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cf5QU/8/

Descriptions for each

```
    var i=0;
    $("a").each(function(){if($(this).css("background")=="blue")i=$(this).index();});

    $(".description-podcast p").html(descri[i]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cf5QU/9/

Comment: I want the description of each item, when selected, not all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because of a server error (a HTTP code != 200).

You might want to:

```
$.getJSON( 
   "[your code]"
).error(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    console.log(e, xhr, settings);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

correct `$(".description-podcast p").text(descri);` to `$(".description-podcast p").html(descri);`

`.text` method would escape any html characters, but `.html` wouldn't.